# Unable to convert byte bluetooth byte array data to real value

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet

I am using a bluetooth app on the android call BlueBotPro. I can successfully connect it to my app on a pc and pass data back and forth. (I am using the 32feet lib for bluetooth)

However, I am having an issue putting the byte array into a readable format.
an example of the byte array I receive from the app is:

```
[0]: 125
[1]: 0
[2]: 0
[3]: 62
[4]: 62
[5]: 249
```

I have tried encoding to ascii (as i thought maybe it was just a string it sends over.) But I had no joy with that and just received

```
"}\0\0>>?"
```

I have tried various encoding types and it seems to have no joy with any of them. 
On the app it shows the joystick input as along the lines of the following

```
x:0 y:0
x:-5 y:125
```

So i would assume the data would send across as such. The app communicates via the serial port bluetooth server. Does this have an impact on how I should be reading the data?

Im quite new to using bluetooth so I'm not 100% sure on whats what so an help / direction pointing would be helpful. I have looked about on SO and not seen anything that I can see as relevant.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: I don't understand. The conversion to ascii looks right, it is what the byte array really contains if you convert it to ascii. What are the values in the byte array supposed to be used as? Is it joystick data from your mobile that you should use in some program on your pc?

Comment: Hi, from what I can tell I believe the data should be a value of x and y and identified as such. The joystick data is from a mobile app that I am wanting to capture within a program on my pc (later porting code to windows IoT for a bot) The trouble is there is not much info from the program as to what I should expect. They have a tutorial for comms with an aurdino http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/magician-android-bluebots but I cannot really see it explaining much. Hopefully that gives you some more info. It may just be easier for me to roll my own bluetooth joystick app